# Is there a way to read either a psv, csv or excel file into a dataframe depending on the file type of the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want the user of a script to enter the file path and name which will be read into a data frame.
The user can enter something like directory1\test1.csv or directory1\test1.psv or directory1\test1.xlsx

Regardless of whether they enter a psv, csv or xlsx, I want to read it into a dataframe with something like following logic:

If file name ends with .psv then df = pd.read_psv(), elif file name ends with .csv then df = read_csv(), elif file name ends with .xlsx then df = pd.read_excel().

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes. If you show a *honest attempt* you could get more help here :-) You current logic looks fine, you should be able to meet your requirement with `filename.lower().endswith(...)`

Comment: You can use the `.endswith()` string method here. Beyond that, please include what you've tried so far based on your own research, and the result of your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is.

```py
import os

# Get the file extension
ext = os.path.splitext(in_file)[1]

if ext == '.psv':
    df = pd.read_psv(in_file)
elif ext == '.csv':
    df = pd.read_csv(in_file)
elif ext == '.xlsx':
    df = pd.read_excel(in_file)
else:
    raise RuntimeError('File extension not recognized')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have tried:

```
#Specify the file directory where it is located
file_path = input("Enter file directory path:")

#Specify the file name where it is located
file_name = input("Enter file name:")

#number of rows to skip to read the column names
skip_rows = input("Skip n rows:")

input_file = file_path + file_name

if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, skiprows = skip_rows)
elif file_name.endswith('.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file, skiprows = skip_rows)
elif file_name.endswith('.psv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep = "|", skiprows = skip_rows)
else: 
    print('file format not supported')
```